# script to gdisk to create a new partition

Tags: shell-script, partition, gdisk, sgdisk

I'm trying to script to `gdisk` to create a new partition of LVM type (for `pvcreate`) so I typed this but I does not work :

```bash
diskModelName=yourDiskModel
diskSerialNumber=yourDiskSerialNumber
lvmPartitionNumber=2
cat<<-EOF | sudo gdisk $disk
p
n


8E00
c
$lvmPartitionNumber
$diskModelName-$diskSerialNumber
p
w
y
EOF
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: I advise using sgdisk. Is is made for automated execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sgdisk` (it should be available from the same package as `gdisk` and it's the same tool just non-interactive). For your case you should be able to use something similar to

```
sgdisk -n $lvmPartitionNumber:0:0 -t $lvmPartitionNumber:8E $disk
```

(the `0:0` part is start and end of the partition and zero is for automatic).

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed, thanks a lot :) !